# Overwrite JAR Maven

Tags: java, maven, overwrite

I am developing a plugin for a piece of software and I need to rapidly compile and test changes that I have made. The software has the ability to reload plugins without restarting which makes it useful to build directly into the plugins folder so testing can be almost immediate. When compiling directly from IntelliJ the previous JAR is overwritten but with Maven the old JAR has to be removed before a new one is created. Is there a way to overwrite old Jars using Maven?

Comment: Use maven -U to force update i.e. maven clean install -U

Comment: `-U` option does not help in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jast take a look into the [maven-jar-plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/index.html) would have shown that there is a configuration element [`forceCreation`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#forceCreation) which exactly solves your purpose.